# Why mvn clean install fails when I put apostrophe in .properties file?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, unicode

I am developing GWT app and I am writing console messages in .properties file. Interesting thing is that I already have some apostrophes in that file, which were created by my team-mates.But when I want to put apostrophe in some message I got error in mvn clean install: [image]

This is my properties file:
[image]

How to add apostrophe in my .properties file?

Comment: I am not sure, but try this 
\\'

Comment: @Moler Again the same error...

Comment: Check the .properties file encoding. Is it uft8?

Answer (score 1):

`Messages` in GWT use the Java `MessageFormat` syntax, so you need to double the apostrophes: `User''s unique name`

Comment: Again the same error.. the thing is that anyone of my team-mates can put apostrophe and it works(they don't put double apostroph or /u0029 they just put aposrtophe and all works).